# Tracking location in android studio (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to use google api with android studio to create a string of code that will track someones location. However when I try to implement locationManager.isProviderEnabled, I get the an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol 'isProviderEnabled'" even though I have the implementation android.location.LocationManager. I honestly can not figure out what is wrong wit my code so if someone can help that would be great!

Here is my code for more reference:

```
 else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                //get the latitude
                double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                //get the longitude
                double longitude = location.getLongitude();
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext());
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    String str = addressList.get(0).getLocality() + ",";
                    str += addressList.get(0).getCountryName();
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(str));
                    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10.2f));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: You should give us more details about your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. GPSLocationService extends Service
2. copy and paste onStart() in your GPSLocationService class

> ```
> @Override
> public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
>
> locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
> listener = new MyLocationListener();
>     if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
>         return;
>     }
>     if (locationManager != null) {
>       if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){           
>         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, listener);
>         locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES, MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, listener);
>     }
>  }
> ```
>
> }